# import npm packages to bare javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, npm

Trying to import an npm package to bare JS/HTML served with python/flask.

```js
<script type="module">

    import { configureChains, createClient } from "./node_modules/@wagmi/core";
    import { bsc } from "./node_modules/@wagmi/core/chains";
    import { Web3Modal } from "./node_modules/@web3modal/html";
    import {EthereumClient,modalConnectors,walletConnectProvider} from "./node_modules/@web3modal/ethereum";


</script>
```

Error message:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: In order to import npm packages into a bare JavaScript HTML file, you can use a module bundler like webpack or Parcel ? If you need help please let me know.

Comment: "i am just trying to import npm package" is not a "just". Nodejs is fundamentally different from the browser, only fully sharing the core JS language itself, not all the APIs that exist on top of that, nor the way scripts are loaded. So unless you know you're working with a universal library (e.g. specifically designed to work in both Node and the browser) you need to transform the node library to something a browser can run by using bundling tools like esbuild, or the older webpack. Also, never give users access to your `node_modules` directory.  Build or copy into a dedicated dir instead.

Comment: Use an [import map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap).

Answer (score 0):

When you `import` or `require` a module in Node.js it has a bunch of rules for converting a module name to a module (including picking particular files out of module directories).

Browsers *don't do that*. When you import a module you need to provide a URL that points to the JS file containing the module.

Your URL points to an HTML document. Probably this is an automatically generated HTML document containing a listing of the files in that directory.

You need to change it to point to the JS file.

---

Aside:

The JS file will also need to be an ES6 module (not a CommonJS module) **and** not depend on any Node.js-specific APIs (such as the `fs` module).

---

Note: Generally people using npm to manage client-side dependencies will use a bundler tool (such as Webpack or Parcel) to convert their modules into a single browser-compatible file. Such tools can take care of the different kinds of module supported by Node.js (although they can't make things like filesystem access work!).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with using `dist/main.js` that webpack created. If you face with this problem you can use webpack easily.